# Вызов конструктора с аргументом null

Tags: c#, .net

Задали интересный вопрос тут на форуме, не могу понять почему вызывается конструктор с параметром типа массив?

**UPDATE:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base ob = new Base(null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Base
{
    public Base(object x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int[]");
    }

    public Base(int[] x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int[]");
    }

    public Base(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int");
    }
}
// output: int[]
```

Comment: Видимо потому, что null в C# не совсем то и число (в отличии от других языков), а в массив преобразовать можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В подобных случаях (то есть при передаче методу null в качестве единственного параметра) компилятор способен самостоятельно решить, какой именно метод (в том числе и конструктор) следует вызывать в двух случаях.

Первый - это когда параметр одного метода является типом-значением, а второго - ссылочным типом. Этот случай был описан в ответе от [[@Alexey123](/users/16416/alexey123)](/users/16416/alexey123), поэтому не будем на нем останавливаться.

Второй более интересен, поскольку не так очевиден. В этом случае компилятор руководствуется следующей логикой. Допрустим, есть два метода:

```
void Method(First x) ;
```

и

```
void Method(Second x);
```

Если First может быть неявно преобразован к Second, а Second не может быть неявно преобразован к First, то будет вызван метод с параметром First. То есть в вашем случае будет вызван **Base(int[] x)** поскольку **int[]** может быть  неявно преобразован к **object**, а вот **object** к **int[]** - нет.

Если же First не может быть неявно преобразован к Second, а Second не может быть преобразован к First, или же если они оба могут быть неявно преобразованы друг к другу (например в случае взаимной реализации оператора implicit), то компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке: **The call is ambiguous  the following between methods or properties** Например:

```
class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator Base(Foo f)
    {
        return new Base(new Foo());
    }
}

class Base
{
    public static implicit operator Foo(Base f)
    {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public Base(Base x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base");
    }

    public Base(Foo x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Base ob = new Base(null); // ошибка 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

или так:

```
class Base
{    
    public Base(Base x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base");
    }

    public Base(int[] x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int[]");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Base ob = new Base(null); // ошибка 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Значение null могут иметь только ссылочные и Nullable типы. Поскольку значение null нельзя присвоить обычному типу int, то никакой неоднозначности не возникает и вызывается конструктор с параметром типа массив, т.к. массив ссылочный тип.

Другое дело, если бы было два конструктора со ссылочными типами или Nullable конструктор:

```
public Base(int? x)
```

тогда бы компилятор выдал предупреждение из-за неоднозначности.

Comment: @Alexey123
Хорошо, а если ещё существует конструктор такой:
 Base(object o) {}.
Компилируется и вызывается 
 Base(int[] x). 

Это как?